# Why simple mysql++ code compiles standalone, but not in project?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

At first, small program:

```
#include <mysql++.h>
using namespace mysqlpp;

void mainuu ()
{ Connection conn("mysql", "localhost", "root", "pwd");}
```

If I compile it as one file in CodeLite or in such way:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp -o Test mysql_api.cpp
```

it's ok
but, when I try to build whole project with this file I get this:

```
g++ -o ./Debug/server ./Debug/main.o ./Debug/log.o ./Debug/packet.o ./Debug/mysql_api.o  -L.   
./Debug/mysql_api.o: In function `mainuu()':
/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server/mysql_api.cpp:10: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::Connection(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server/mysql_api.cpp:12: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::query(char const*)'
/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server/mysql_api.cpp:13: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::SQLTypeAdapter::SQLTypeAdapter(char const*, bool)'
/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server/mysql_api.cpp:13: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::operator<<(mysqlpp::quote_type1, mysqlpp::SQLTypeAdapter const&)'
/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server/mysql_api.cpp:19: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, mysqlpp::String const&)'
/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server/mysql_api.cpp:10: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::~Connection()'
/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server/mysql_api.cpp:10: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::~Connection()'
./Debug/mysql_api.o: In function `mysqlpp::Row::operator[](int) const':
/usr/include/mysql++/row.h:328: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Row::at(unsigned int) const'
./Debug/mysql_api.o: In function `mysqlpp::Query::store()':
/usr/include/mysql++/query.h:467: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Query::str(mysqlpp::SQLQueryParms&)'
/usr/include/mysql++/query.h:467: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::SQLTypeAdapter::SQLTypeAdapter(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/include/mysql++/query.h:467: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Query::store(mysqlpp::SQLTypeAdapter const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Debug/server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/asyler/.codelite/workspace/test/server'
make: *** [All] Error 2
```

Here is CodeLite g++ compiler settings:

```
-g -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql++ -lmysql++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to edit CodeLite project settings and add these settings `-lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp` that you pass in command line. Fill [**Library Path** and **Libraries** fields on **Linker** tab](http://codeliteorg.ipage.com/LiteEditor/ProjectSettings).

Comment: You don't need include directories when linking objects.

Comment: Oh.. It works some how.
Now after successful compilation CodeLite doesn't create an executable.
I think it's my fault. Try to find it

Comment: Actually, now I confused about linker options. Can you tell what I need to fill in linker options?

Comment: Just fill in **Libraries** field `mysqlclient mysqlpp`

Comment: It still doesn't create an executable

Comment: Finally, I've got it. In way, CodeLite understand it's look next: mysqlclient;mysqlpp;

Comment: Try this `mysqlclient mysqlpp mysql++` for **Libraries**

Comment: and this `/usr/lib/mysql /usr/lib/mysql++` for **Library Path**

Answer (score 1):

Those are *linker* errors.

When you create your final executable, you still must provide references to all library functions, just as you did when you compiled the single translation unit.

So, pass `-lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp` to `g++` this time, too.

If you are using an Integrated Development Environment, configure your project's build settings accordingly. In particular, I see that [CodeLite has both "Compiler" and "Linker" build settings](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/ProjectSettings). It's "Linker" settings that you're after.

For more information on the build process (i.e. compiling, linking and the difference), read a good C++ book.

Comment: Nothing changed.
Here is my compiler oprions: -g -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql++ -lmysql++

Comment: @vladimar: You changed the wrong options. None of those are being used for the final build phase: you can see that in the output that you showed us. Look for _linker_ options, not _compiler_ options.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do in this way